# I want to convert a hexadecimal byte array to hexadecimal in string format

Tags: python, hex, byte

I want to convert byte format to string format.
The conversion target is as follows.
\xb9S\xfc\x81\xe4\xa2\xb9\x92\x8d\xbb1\xfe\xb9\xa1&\x16\ ......
Convert to string format.

For example,
b'\xfc\x81\xe4\xa2\xb9\x92' #type:bytes -> "FC 81 E4 A2 B9 92" #type:str

No matter how much I searched, I couldn't find the module by myself.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def format_bytes_as_hex(b: bytes) -> str:
    h = b.hex()
    return ' ' .join(f'{a}{b}'.upper() for a, b in zip(h[0::2], h[1::2]))


Test:
format_bytes_as_hex(b'\xfc\x81\xe4\xa2\xb9\x92')
'FC 81 E4 A2 B9 92'
```

Answer (score 1):

[This is implemented in the standard lib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.hex)

Starting with python 3.5, you got this :

```py
val = b'AAAAA'
print(val.hex())
    
# prints '4141414141'
```

With python 3.8+, you can also specify a separator :

```py
val = b'AAAAA'
print(val.hex(' '))
    
# prints '41 41 41 41 41'
```

if you absolutely want them in uppercase, you can call `upper()` on the result.